# Long-distance relationship, planning to visit US partner from UK for Christmas

Tags: usa, us-visa-waiver-program

I'm British and planning to visit my partner in Florida for Christmas. It's a long-distance relationship and we've been speaking for a while. I never thought I'd see the day when I'd find myself in a long-distance relationship but it happened.

I'm planning to visit for a month and a half or a little more, which is fine under the VWP. I will be arriving with a return ticket and enough money to support myself, plus I will be staying with my partner and his family. I'm also planning to visit my own family who lives in the U.S. I could make sure to get their address if needed for when I arrive at the airport. I will be flying to Atlanta and will be picked up by my boyfriend before driving to Florida.

I'm a nervous traveler, so this may just be me being silly, but I'm anxious about the attitude I'll receive given that it's a gay relationship. Will there be any problem entering the U.S.? I obviously plan on telling the immigration officer how the person is my partner if asked because it's the truth. I'll be arriving with around $1,000 to support myself during that time and I will also be getting money into my bank whilst away.

If this is a silly question I'm sorry but I'm just curious as to what difficulties I may face or if I'm overreacting. Thank you.

Comment: I think it is highly unlikely that the agent with care about gay. You might want to be prepared to show why you will return to the UK; this would be true of all LDRs.

Comment: Same-sex marriage is legal in the USA now, so I might be worried that the US immigration official might think you are intending to get married and request a spousal visa. Do you have strong ties to the UK that indicate that you are likely to return there as opposed to trying to move in with your partner?

Answer (score 8):

You do need to document how you will be supported while in the US, but that is probably not the main problem you will face.

Someone with both family and a boyfriend in the US is likely to be seen as high risk for overstaying. You will need to convince the US authorities that you really do intend to return to the UK at the end of your planned trip.

Do you have a job you need to return to? School or college? Other commitments, such as family members you look after? Property you own? You should carry evidence of anything that ensures you will go home.

Answer (score 4):

"**given that it's a gay relationship**" - CBP is uninterested in this detail.

You will be evaluated as an immigration risk just like everyone else.

"**I'm also planning to visit my own family who lives in the U.S.**" - then make this your opening statement *provided it is in fact true*.  You should have their address and know at least the town where they live.